# Как получить название, которое я выдал QCheckBox

Tags: c++, qt

```
include <QCheckBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCheckBox* lessonRussianLanguage = new QCheckBox("Russian Language");
QString lessonName = russianLanguage->   //какой метод класса QCheckBox я должен использовать, чтобы получить его название
}
```

Comment: просто `->text()`

Comment: `Russian Language` это не название, а свойство `text`, название это `objectName`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за то, что указали на мою ошибку в постановлении вопроса)